# Why do a shaken coca-cola can and an unshaken one roll at different velocities from an inclined plane?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I read somewhere (I don't know if it's true; I didn't try it) that if you shake one coca-cola can wildly and do nothing with another, they roll at different velocities from an inclined plane, the unshaken one arriving at the bottom first. Why is this?
The coca-cola inside the shaken can somehow start to rotate easier in the shaken can. But why? Because of the higher pressure, wich gives the coca-cola more "grip" on the metal of the can? Or what?

EDIT:
I bought two cola cans and shook one up very hard. Then I placed them on a long and broad piece of inclined wood, and the shaken one did indeed arrive later at the bottom. To see how the arrival time depends on the slope of the wood would also be interesting, but I haven't done that yet.

Comment: "I don't know if it's true; I didn't try it" Do the experiment before trying to explain it?

Comment: @Gremlin-I'm surely gonna buy two cans!

Comment: It might have something to do with surface pressure.  The higher pressure can stays rounder while the less pressurized can flattens out more and therefore wouldn't roll as easily.

Comment: @JMac-According to me it was the high-pressure can that rolled down slower.

Comment: @descheleschilder Your second paragraph suggested the opposite of your first paragraph.  If the high pressure coca-cola started to rotate easier then it would be rolling faster.

Comment: @Jmac-I wrote that the *cola* inside the high pressure can starts to rotate easier, thereby increasing its energy. If the cola in a can wouldn't rotate, gravity would only have the can to rotate (and gravity works off course on the mass of the coca-cola). But if the cola rotates the can gets a higher moment of inertia which makes it more difficult for gravity to accelerate its angular velocity. The cola's $E_{kin}$ in the low-pressure can doesn't increase as much as the $E_{kin}$ of the cola in the high-pressure can, provided by gravity, so gravity gives more rotation to the low-pressure can.

Comment: @descheleschilder I don't really understand what you're saying now.  Rotational energy and transnational velocity are kinetic energy.  There's going to be rotation in the cola regardless.  I'm not exactly sure how pressure would effect that.  Higher pressure might decrease the size of the air space on top, which would increase the inertia.

Comment: @Jmac-But the point is: which of the two fluids of cola acquire more rotation? I don't have the answer either, but I tried it with two cans and the shaken one did indeed take longer to reach the floor. If the rotation of the cola has increased more, due to gravity, then gravity has less left to accelerate the shaken can.

Comment: The moment of inertia of the cans are obviously different. Therefore, there will be a difference in the time taken to roll down.

Comment: @descheleschilder the fluids acquiring rotation wont be an issue if they have a low resistance to that rotation (inertia).  The problem will be that one will require more energy to rotate.  The rotation speed will still almost directly correlate to velocity as there should be almost no slip between the can and the surface it rolls down (i.e. distance traveled is angle rotated times the radius).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The moment of inertia of the two cans is different.

The can contains a carbonated drink. When you shake it, the gas inside the liquid tries to escape. As it tries to escape, it carries some parts of the liquid as well; it creates a foam above the liquid which spreads over the volume unoccupied by the liquid (the foam cannot escape so it will try to cover most of the unused volume).

In the can which wasn't shaken, there is more soda in liquid form. Liquid being denser, settles down.

The liquid in the can which was shaken is slightly less compared to the unshaken can, this liquid settles as well but the liquid which was converted to foam distributes over a large area.

This would imply that the moment of inertia of the two cans are different. The can with a smaller moment of inertia will move faster.

I am not sure which one has a larger moment of inertia. It most likely depends on amount of volume consumed by the liquid, how much you shook, the concentration of the gas, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52832/discussion-between-jmac-and-descheleschilder).

Answer (score 1):

Shaking the can strongly will create foam. As the can rolls, foam will cling to the "uphill" side of the can as the liquid "hamster wheels" the can forward down the inclined plane.  The result is a "drag" (negative weight torque) on the forward rolling force of the can (positive weight torque of fluid on the downhill side of the contact point with the ramp).

Any foam on the sides also reduces the volume of liquid at the bottom of the can, also reducing rolling force.

Undisturbed liquid will not adhere to the can sides as much, leaving less residue on the sides while the can is turning.

Note that the mixture of ingredients, not just gas release, may create foam when strongly shaken.  A similar experiment could be done with a soap/water solution, with a "control" run on the same can after it has settled down.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if I agree with your assessment. I have two other plausible theories. But first you stated that when you shake it up it creates a foam in the can. This actually isn’t true. The kinetic energy from shaking the can does release some of the liquid CO2 into gas but that’s not what creates the foam. That from suspended CO2 rushing to the top through the liquid when you open it. That rushing creates more kinetic energy thereby releasing more g liquid to gas and creating a foam. You can test this by shaking a can then tapping it along the side and notice that no further kinetic energy releases any more gas and that means no foam, because all the initial gas is not at the top of the can.

Theory one. Simple yet most plausible. The increased pressure expands the outside of the can by just a small amount but then acts like an over inflated car tire. Less traction equals more resistance meaning slower movement.

Theory two. I don’t have this fully formed in my head because it’s has to do with how I stumbled on this in the first place, having googled something else for an explanation. Does the liquid in the can spin with the can or does the can flow across the stable liquid. In a separate experiment a rolling can will not shake the liquid and therefore will not create fuzz. I wanted the answer to this question. Does it roll with the can or remain stationary. I found this. If it remains stationary with increased pressure that would also increase resistance as the can tries to roll across it, causing the can to slow down. However if the liquid rolls with the can and it’s pressurized that would also increase the amount of kinetic energy needed to start this movement but not to keep it going. This can be tested by changing the lengths of the boards and determine if it’s only the initial start that slowed or the entire trip.

Comment: HI George, welcome on Physics Stack Exchange! I just want to make sure that you realize that this is a Q&A site and not a forum. So, if you post an answer it is a answer to the question on the top, and not a response to another answer. Maybe you want to update your first paragraph accordingly?